# Undefined is not an object (evaluating "this.props.navigation.navigate")

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am making my first React Native App and I got this error: `Undefined is not an object (evaluating "this.props.navigation.navigate")` at this part of the code:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>choose festival</Text>
        <Button
        title="Select SummerBurst 2017"
        onPress={() =>
          this.props.navigation.navigate('FestivalScreen', { name: 'SummerBurst' })
        }
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I think this is because I don't pass down the react-navigation props, but I don't really know how to do this. My repo looks like this: https://github.com/meurling/festivalApp

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you want to learn first using `react-navigation` on ReactNative. You follow this tutorial :

[Tutorial React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/)

And then, if you already understand the flow of `react-navigation`. You can play and combine with your idea.

just suggest for you. i hope can help you to easy learning this library.

About your problem, because there are steps you miss, maybe...keep fighting!! keep coding!! cahyooo..